# Show alert while after selecting maximum images using TLPhotoPicker

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I'm using `TLPhotoPicker` to open my gallery and pick images from that. On the tap of a button to open the gallery, this is the code I have in my viewcontroller file..

```
   fileprivate func openImagePicker() {
       imagePickerConfig.allowsMultiple = true
        imagePickerConfig.openContributeImagePicker()
          imagePickerConfig.delegate = self
           imagePickerConfig.selectedImage() { [weak self] imageInfo in
             guard let `self` = self else { return }
             if let image = imageInfo?.image {
               self.imageName = imageInfo?.name ?? "profile.png"
             }
           }
      }
```

The `openContributeImagePicker()` function is given as below in my `pickerConfigClass`..

```
 func openContributeImagePicker()
  {
    configure.singleSelectedMode = false
    configure.maxSelectedAssets = 5
    customPicker.configure = configure
    viewController?.present(customPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

Here in the gallery, I can select only 5 images. And after that I cannot select another image. But when I try to select more than 5 images, I want to show an alert while I'm still in the gallery itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let viewController = CustomPhotoPickerViewController()
        viewController.delegate = self
        viewController.didExceedMaximumNumberOfSelection = { [weak self] (picker) in
            self?.showExceededMaximumAlert(vc: picker)
        }
        var configure = TLPhotosPickerConfigure()
        configure.numberOfColumn = 3
        configure.maxSelectedAssets = 5
        viewController.configure = configure
        viewController.selectedAssets = self.selectedAssets
        viewController.logDelegate = self

        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

func didExceedMaximumNumberOfSelection(picker: TLPhotosPickerViewController) {
        self.showExceededMaximumAlert(vc: picker)
    }
func showExceededMaximumAlert(vc: UIViewController) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Exceed Maximum Number Of Selection", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jins George..:)